# JS Regex to find and replace uses of variable

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I am very new to regex and i am trying to figure out if there is a way to do a regex which matches all the uses of a variable in a string, assuming the string represents valid javascript code, for example:

I have this variable name "data"
And i want to replace all uses of variable name "data" with "array[i]"

If i have this code(string):

```js
data.min + someObject.data > 10 && data.max + someObject.data < 20
```

I expect

```js
array[i].min + someObject.data > 10 && array[i].max + someObject.data < 20
```

I tried

```js
let findString = `(?<=\\s|^|"|{|\\()\\b(${localVar})\\b`;
```

But there are certain scenarios that don't work with that like, it matches strings within quotes, which are not variables and mainly lookbehind/lookahead doesn't seem to work in Sarafi

At the moment i ended up doing a very "manual" solution which iterates the entire string and checks for instances of the variable name but i still believe there should be a way to achieve what i want trough regex.

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer is that you would need a context-aware lexer or parser that can tell the difference between `data.min`, `someObject.data.min` and `"text with data.min in it"`.

Some editors, like VS Code, have a basic parser built-in and can do basic [variable renaming](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_rename-symbol) within the same file. TypeScript extensions can take that even further because you have additional layers of type-awareness.

Unfortunately, a regex is generally not context-aware (enough) to be sufficient to the job, however you can often muddle through if you can make some assumptions.

For example, you can write a regex like this:

```
(?<!\.)\b(data)\b
```

`\b(data)\b` will find instances of `data` which are prefixed and postfixed with non-word characters. So it will find the "data" in `data.bar` and `data = "foo"` but it will exclude `somedata` and `dataObj`.

The `(?<!\.)` will exclude instances which are prefixed by a period. So it will exclude `someObject.data` but not `data.max`.

That regex should be sufficient for the examples you gave:

```
"data.min + someObject.data > 10 && data.max + someObject.data < 20".replaceAll(/(?<!\.)\b(data)\b/g, "array[i]");

// Produces: "array[i].min + someObject.data > 10 && array[i].max + someObject.data < 20"
```

However, I can't guarantee it will find all of the instances in your code or that every instance it finds will be correct. It's very easy to break:

```
"data.min + someObject. data > 10 && 'data.max' + someObject.data < 20".replaceAll(/(?<!\.)\b(data)\b/g, "array[i]")

// Produces: "array[i].min + someObject. array[i] > 10 && 'array[i].max' + someObject.data < 20"
```

Assuming this is a one-time, time-saving exercise, it's probably enough that it'll find *most* instances with *good enough* accuracy, but it's not something that would be reliable for blind processing. For example, I would not trust it in a script that finds/replaces across a hundred JS files.

> *"i still believe there should be a way to achieve what i want trough regex"*

You may want to check what you are basing your belief on. I would recommend that you [read up](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/) on Regexes and what they are and aren't capable of doing. It's easy to believe they are far more powerful than they are.

[image: A manager asks an engineer to write an app that can check whether a photo was taken in a national park. The engineer responds that it will be easy. The manager then asks the engineer to also check whether the photo contains an image of a bird. The engineer replies that they will need a research team and five years. A message below reads: In CS, it can be hard to explain the difference between the easy and the virtually impossible.]